# Parameter estimation for a distribution by minimizing its conditional entropy

Tags: probability-distributions, information-theory, parameter-estimation, entropy

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable with [Laplacian distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) with mean $0$ and scale $\lambda$, as

$$
p(X) = \frac{1}{2\lambda} \exp\left(-\frac{|x|}{2\lambda}\right), \\

X \in \{0,1,...,255\}.
$$

Suppose we have $N$ observations $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_N\}$ for $X$ and want to estimate the $\lambda$. One solution is to use [Maximum likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) method which simply [estimates $\lambda$ as the mean of $x_i$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Parameter_estimation).

My confusion is about another solution employed in a C++ code. Apparently the implemented approach is to estimate $\lambda$ such that *minimizes the conditional entropy*. Here is the this code:

*You can skip this code. I have represented it as a mathematical expression in the following*

```
double BestLambda, BestEntropy;
BestEntropy = LARGE;
for (double lambda = 0; lambda <= 10.0; lambda += 0.01) {
    // Form Q vector
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        pQVec[i] = exp( -lambda * abs(i) );
        sum += pQVec[i];
    }
    //Normalize pQVec
    for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
    {
        pQVec[i] = pQVec[i] / sum;
    }

    // Calculate conditional entropy
    double EntropySum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        if (XFreq[i] > 0) {
            EntropySum -= (XFreq[i] * log(pQVec[i])/log(2.0));
        }
    }

    // Compare against best entropy
    if (EntropySum < BestEntropy) {
        BestEntropy = EntropySum;
        BestLambda = lambda;
    }
}
```

In the mathematical terms, this program estimates $\lambda$ in this way,

$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\hat\lambda = \argmin_{\lambda} \left\{ - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{255} f(x=i)\log_2(p_{\lambda}(x=i)) \right\},
$$

where $f(x=i)$ is the frequency of $x$'s with value $i$ in the samples and $p_\lambda(x)$ is a Laplacian distribution with mean 0 and scale $\lambda$.

While this code is implemented and [published](http://www.stanford.edu/~dmchen/dvc.html) by the guys at Stanford and supported by [their highly-cited paper](http://ivms.stanford.edu/~varodayan/publications/Varodayan_08ImageComm_WZVideoMotionLearning.pdf), I have doubt if their approach in estimating $\lambda$ is accurate. I have studied a little bit on Information Theory and cannot figure out what we are actually minimizing in this expression.

Shouldn't we minimize the distance between two distributions? Using [Kullback–Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) we could estimate $\lambda$ as

$$
\hat\lambda = \argmin_{\lambda} \left\{ D(f(x)||p_{\lambda}(x) ) \right\}

= \argmin_{\lambda} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{255} \left[ f(x=i)\log_2\left(\frac{f(x=i)}{p_{\lambda}(x=i)}\right) \right] \right\} .

$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, for the shake of exactness, a discrete random variable cannot have a Laplace distribution which is a continuous distribution for continuous rv's. If your variable is by nature discrete, then you should look to the [discrete analogue of the Laplace distribution](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378375804003519). But I assume that you have a continuous rv but naturally only a finite discrete sample.

Then, regarding your question, what the code does is exactly minimizing KL distance. Look at the argmin operation you propose: you have the logarithm of a ratio - so it can be additively broken into a positive part (which does not depend on lambda and so is irrelevant for the minimization procedure), and a negative part, which depends on lambda and which is exactly what the code attempts to minimize: you won't get the *value* of the minimized distance/divergence, but you will get the lambda that minimizes it.

Comment: Wow thanks! Didn't expected to be that simple. And yes, the random variable is continuous and we have samples from a finite domain.